# Max width does not work in my practice code

Tags: css

I'm learning CSS with W3school,in max width lesson, it was said the max-width is the maximum width of an element
So in this code i see this rule is not actually work!

```
<style>
div {
  width:499px;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: powderblue;
}
</style>
```

When i increase the padding , the width on the site will also increase.
What is the missing point in this lesson?
In what circumstances the max-width will work correctly?

Comment: `I'm learning CSS with W3school` That’s probably a bad idea. A good site would talk about `box-sizing` before talking about `max-width` and `padding`.

Answer (score -1):

The problem can be solved when you add this to your CSS code.

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

I suggest watching some tutorials about this line of code.